# bad argument type for built-in operation

Tags: python, opencv

Hello I am trying to read images from the specified directory and want to write the text line by line (that too i m reading from the text file specified) and saving images(text on that images) into other directory specified. But facing the following error.

**Code:**

```
import cv2
import glob
import shutil 
import os  
import numpy as np  #for copying and moving files 
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

input_path = 'C:\\Users\\Kazmi-PC\\OneDrive\\Pictures\\1\\*.*'
output_path = 'C:\\Users\\Kazmi-PC\\OneDrive\\Pictures\\2\\'
file_name = 'C:\\Users\\Kazmi-PC\\OneDrive\\Pictures\\3\\code.txt'



def read_file():
   if os.path.isfile(file_name):
       rows = []
       with open (file_name, mode='r') as file:
            for line in file:
                rows.append(line.strip())
       return rows
   else:
       raise Exception('file name does not exist')


def images_1(input_path, output_path):
    for im in glob.glob(input_path):
        image = cv2.imread(im)
        if im is None:
            raise Exception ("images are not found")
        else:
            print("printing.....")
            i= 0
            for i in im:
                text= read_file()
                img =  cv2.putText(image, text ,(100,100), font,4, 
                        (225,225,225),cv2.LINE_AA ) 

                cv2.imwrite(output_path + '\\_img' + str(i) + '_.jpg', 
                               img)

 images_1(input_path, output_path)
```

**Error:**

> **TypeError:** bad argument type for built-in operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text` in `cv2.putText` function should be of type `string`, but is `list` in your case as `read_file()` returns a list named `rows`. 
So, replace `text` in `cv2.putText` function to `str(text)` or `''.join(text)` or `'\n'.join(text)`, etc.

**Code:**

```
img =  cv2.putText(image, str(text), (100,100), font, 4, (225,225,225), cv2.LINE_AA)
```